# Arithmetic Coding Algorithm C/Java. Cumulative frequencies

Tags: java, c, compression

C related question on topic "Arithmetic Coding Algorithm". I am currently implementing Arithmetic Coding algorithm in Java and have a couple of lines of code that doesn't make sense to me.

1. If we have an alphabet that has less characters than unsigned byte can hold, e.g, 47 unique characters, how could cumulative frequencies be indexed (according to this expression):

`high = low + (range * cum_freq[symbol-1]) / cum_freq[0] - 1;`

For example, symbol "U" has a value of 85 in ASCII code, but cum_freq[84] does not exist.

2. What is the point of a for loop on line 189 in Arithmetic decoding algorithm? Does it simply increment symbol by one?

`for (symbol = 1; cum_freq[symbol]>cum; symbol++);`

Source:
Arithmetic coding for data compression, Communications of The ACM, 1987
https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee398a/handouts/papers/WittenACM87ArithmCoding.pdf

Comment: C and Java are two different languages. The paper has C code. And K&R C at that, not even ANSI C. Java was not even been created when that paper was released. What does Java to do with your questions?

Comment: Why do you say that  cum_freq[84] does not exist?

Comment: @aled  "I am currently implementing Arithmetic Coding algorithm in Java".

Comment: Your question is not about Java or how to implement something in Java. It is about understanding the original C algorithm. The Java tag is not relevant.

Comment: Because the number of elements in cum_freq array is equal to the number of unique characters in the file that needs to be compressed.

Comment: First, the number of elements in `cum_freq` is the number of unique symbols _plus two_. One for the end symbol and one for their origin 1 indexing. Second, it is the number of symbols that _could_ be in the file. Not all of those symbols are _required_ to be in the file. You could have a file with just one symbol, that same symbol repeated many times. (Which will compress very well, by the way.) `cum_freq[84]` absolutely exists. It would just be equal to zero.

Comment: It says right there in the comment on line 189 that you left out: "Then find symbol." That `for` loop sets `symbol` equal to the first symbol whose frequency is greater than `cum`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `cum_freq` is defined in `model.h` to have 258 elements. Enough for the single byte characters encodings of the '80s. Awful use of '+1' abuse in array definitions.

```
#define No-of-chars 256 
#define No-of-symbols (No-of-chars+1)
...
int cum_freq[No_of_symbols+1];
```

2. The point seems to find the first index in the array that doesn't match the condition. Old C programs don't communicate intention well.

Comment: Do you know how the smaller number of elements could be indexed? What if my alphabet is 47 elements long (not 258)?

Comment: Just use it as is. The frequencies of the 209 unused symbols will be zero.

Comment: Ok, so the use of EOF symbol is excess, if we use the condition of a for loop (for each byte in encoded byte array)?

Comment: And, by the way, do the frequencies in ``freq[]`` array have to be sorted?